# Error: Junk at EOL, first unrecognised character is '('

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, quake

I am trying to compile Quake 1 (QW) from source code and have run into the following problem when compiling `client/d_copy.s` : `Error: Junk at EOL, first unrecognised character is '('`.

The file in question is [here](http://pastebin.com/awvtgrAu) (please excuse the syntax highlighting, pastebin only supports NASM). I am attempting to compile with GCC (as this is GNU Assembly code) and am trying to figure out what is causing the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `C(VGA_UpdatePlanarScreen):` isn't a valid label. The assembler will see `(` as unrecognized. You can't use parentheses in a label or variable name.

Comment: Please update this question with the relevant code _in the question_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembly file is meant to be run through the C preprocessor before being sent to the assembler. This should result in the `C` macro being properly expanded, assuming that the macro been defined in the one of the other files that are included by the `#include` lines.

To have GCC preprocess the assembly file you can either use the `-x assembler-with-cpp` option or rename the file so that it has a `.S` (capital S) or `.sx` extension.